# getChildRoutes block parent rendering

Tags: react-router

I've tried using `setTimout` ( 10 sec ) in `getChildRoutes` to simulate low latency network. let say www.example.com/user,  I got server side rendering on `"/user"` path. when I access `/user`, I got blank page instead of the page from server side rendering, then after 10 sec,  I get my page rendering.

```
var routes = [{
path: '/',
component: App,
indexRoute: { component: DashBoardPage },
getChildRoutes(location, cb) {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        console.log("set sleep");
        setTimeout(function () {
            var test = [{path: 'about', component: DashBoardPage},
                {path: 'feed', component: FeedChannelPage},
                {path: 'host', component: HostPage},
                {path: 'user', component: UserPage}];
            console.log("location is " + location);
            cb(null, test);
        }, 10000);
    }else{
        var test = [{path: 'about', component: DashBoardPage},
            {path: 'feed', component: FeedChannelPage},
            {path: 'host', component: HostPage},
            {path: 'user', component: UserPage}];
        console.log("location is " + location);
        cb(null, test);
    }


}
}]
export default routes;
```

This my App.jsx

```
class App extends React.Component {
render () {
    return (
        <div id="wrapper">
            <nav className="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style={{marginBottom: 0}}>
                <div className="navbar-header">
                    <a className="navbar-brand" href="index.html">SB Admin v2.0</a>
                </div>
                <div className="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
                    <div className="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
                        <ul className="nav" id="side-menu">
                            <li className="sidebar-search">
                                <div className="input-group custom-search-form">
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <Link to="/about"><i className="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Dashboard</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <Link to="/host"><i className="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Host</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <Link to="/user"><i className="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> User</Link>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div id="page-wrapper" style={{'minHeight':'400px'}}>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

Comment: when call ReactDom.render() it render noscript tag instead of render my <div id ="wrapper">...<div>. Why does it not render <div id="wrapper">..<div> and then render {this.props.children} once getChildRoutes() has finished

Comment: when i use getChildRoutes() function, react-router not render "/" component. Say, I use setTimeout function in getChildRoutes() function to delay. I've got noscript tag. Why react-router does not render "/" component ahead and inject children after getChildRoutes() is completed.